# dplyr and ggplot piping is not working as expected

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I find no solution for these two following issues:

First I try this:

```
library(tidyverse)
gg <- mtcars %>% 
      mutate(group=ifelse(gear==3,1,2)) %>%      
      ggplot(aes(x=carb, y=drat)) + geom_point(shape=group)

Error in layer(data = data, mapping = mapping, stat = stat, geom = 
GeomPoint,:object 'group' not found
```

which is obviously not working. But using something like this `.$group` is also not successfull. Of note, I have to specifiy the shape outside from `aes()`

The second problem is this. I'm not able to call a saved ggplot (`gg`) within a pipe.

```
gg <- mtcars %>% 
      mutate(group=ifelse(gear==3,1,2)) %>%      
      ggplot(aes(x=carb, y=drat)) + geom_point()


    mtcars %>% 
        filter(vs == 0) %>% 
        gg + geom_point(aes(x=carb, y=drat), size = 4)  

Error in gg(.) : could not find function "gg"
```

Thanks for your help!

## Edit

After a long time I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45088454/how-do-i-access-the-data-frame-that-has-been-passed-to-ggplot/45088522#45088522). One has to set the complete ggplot term in `{}`.

```
mtcars %>% 
   mutate(group=ifelse(gear==3,1,2)) %>% {     
   ggplot(.,aes(carb,drat)) +
       geom_point(shape=.$group)}
```

Comment: try `geom_point(aes(shape=factor(group)))` and for the second part you need `{}` as in `mtcars %>% filter(vs == 0) %>% {gg + geom_point(data = ., aes(x=carb, y=drat), size = 4)}`

Comment: In the first part I need this `ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=carb, y=drat)) + geom_point(shape=ifelse(mtcars$gear==3,1,2))`. Thum up for the second part!

Comment: i had never seen the `{}` trick with `ggplot` before. nice solution

Comment: @docendodiscimus Then piping is not possible with ggplot if one have to set a variable outside `aes()`?

Comment: And I'm wondering why the question has two votes for closing?

Comment: Why do you need to set shape outside of `aes`?

Comment: @drmariod just for curiostiy and because it makes no sense in my eyes regarding the piping rules. But honestly I have no idea why I needed this at that time....

Comment: I think, if you want to access a column, this is only possible within the `aes` function. If you try this outside, it tries to access a variable. You can set this separately and access it like this `group <- ifelse(mtcars$gear==3,1,2) ; ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=carb, y=drat)) + geom_point(shape=factor(group))`. But I guess this is not the best way. With the `{}` it should also be possible to use within piping.

Answer (score 2):

If you wrap your `shape` definition in `aes()` you can get the desired behavior.  To use `shape` outside of `aes()` you can pass it a single value (ie `shape=1`).  Also note that `group` is converted to a discrete var, `geom_point` throws an error when you pass a continuous var to `shape`.

```
library(tidyverse)

gg <- mtcars %>% 
  mutate(group=ifelse(gear==3,1,2)) %>%      
  ggplot(aes(x=carb, y=drat)) + 
  geom_point(aes(shape=as.factor(group)))

gg
```

Second, the `%>%` operator, when called as `lhs %>% rhs`, assumes that the `rhs` is a function.  So as the error shows, you are calling `gg` as a function.  Calling a plot as a function on a dataframe (ie `gg(mtcars)`) isnt a valid operation.

See @docendo discimus comment on the question for how to use `{}` to accomplish adding a layer to an existing `ggplot` object from a magrittr pipeline.

Comment: But I want this: `ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=carb, y=drat)) + geom_point(shape=ifelse(mtcars$gear==3,1,2))`. So I can't use piping in both cases?

Comment: You first code block accomplishes that call to `ggplot`, but you can't predefine the plot and then call it as a function.  If you want to call the code used to generate `gg` on a different dataframe then you can wrap it in a function before using in the pipeline

Comment: Thanks. But nevertheless I need to set the shape outside `aes()`. Seems not possible with piping then.