# How do I access the data frame that has been passed to ggplot()?

Tags: r, ggplot2, magrittr

I want to set the string `N=xxx` as the title of my figure, where `xxx` is the number of observations in the data frame that I pass as the `data` argument to `ggplot()`. In my current code, I explicitly pass that data frame a second time as an argument to `sprintf()` which I use inside of `labs()`:

```r
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, hp)) + 
    labs(title=sprintf("N=%i", nrow(mtcars))) + 
    geom_point()
```

This does produce the desired title, but it won't work with more complex tasks: I use a `dplyr` pipe to construct the data frame that is being plotted, and as this is a time-consuming process, I wouldn't want to repeat the pipe a second time to obtain the number of rows like in the example.

So, how do I access the data frame that has been passed as an argument to `ggplot()` from within the argument specifications of the functions that are used to modify the plot?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

```
mtcars %>% {
  ggplot(., aes(mpg, hp)) + 
  labs(title = paste("N =", nrow(.))) + 
  geom_point()
}
```

Note that when wrapping the whole `ggplot` call in `{...}` curly braces, you must use the `.` dot pronoun for the data argument in `ggplot(., ...)`. Then you can call back that object using the `.` pronoun anywhere in the call.

[image]

Comment: Excellent, this is exactly what I was looking for. I vaguely remembered something about using `.`, but didn't know where to look that up. Thanks to your answer, I found that this is described in the `magrittr` vignette: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/vignettes/magrittr.html

Comment: You can also use `sprintf` instead of `paste` of course, for more control over the formatting.

Comment: This is very nice, I didn't think of using {} to create an "function" like this.

Comment: @rsmith54, I find myself doing it all the time with `%>%` and non-tidyverse functions that put the `data` argument later on, like `lmer`.

Comment: Yeah, it is a really nice trick.  I wonder if it would be useful to add some information on the mechanism to the answer as well.

Comment: Why does this not work with "ggcorr" which is also based on "ggplot2"?

Comment: @ÖmerAn I've never used `ggcorr` but looking at its documentation, I see no reason it shouldn't work the same. Can you open a new question with your code that's not working?

Answer (score 12):

Another option that takes advantage of another of `magrittr`'s pipe-lining features: the tee operator `%T>%`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(magrittr)
# to solidify where the variable will be out-of-scope defined
nr <- "oops"
mtcars %T>%
  { nr <<- nrow(.) } %>%
  ggplot(aes(mpg, hp)) + 
    labs(title=sprintf("N=%i", nr)) + 
  geom_point()
```

(This can also be done using `dplyr`'s `do({nr <<- nrow(.)}) %>%`.)

This differs from Brian's answer in two ways:

1. Subjectively "cleaner looking", in that the `ggplot` code is not indented within a code block. (As commented, though, the blending of different pipelines could be a negative as well.)
2. It has side-effect, by creating `nr` outside of the pipeline and ggplot pipes. By pre-assigning `nr`, I think this mitigates reaching outside of the local environment, but it's still a little sloppy.

Comment: I agree with your assessment in (2) that this is a bit sloppy due to its side effects, which is why I prefer Brian's answer. But this still is a very interesting use of the tee operator.

Comment: Subjectively, I (of course, haha) prefer having the `ggplot` call set off within braces. That makes it a cleaner separation between processing and plotting objects in the chain.

Comment: Good point, Brian, the hybrid pipelines have always been "visually disturbing". Schmuddi -- agree fully. It would be nice (albeit 100s of hours of work and breaking incompatibility) if `ggplot2` honored `%>%` instead of overloading `+`.

Comment: There was an attempt at reconciling them: https://github.com/thomasp85/pipeplotter  e.g. `ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) %>% add_points()`

Comment: Also: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/1954, referring to a [tweet by Hadley](https://twitter.com/hadleywickham/status/648851767254380545) about the pipe and 20/20 hindsight.