# accessing data of the plot within ggtitle

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggtitle

I am wondering if it is somehow possible to access the columns of the provided data within a `ggplot2` graph for the title. So something like that:

```
ggplot(mpg %>% filter(manufacturer == 'audi'), 
  aes(x = hwy, y = displ, label = model)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    geom_text(data = . %>% filter(hwy > 28)) + 
    ggtitle(unique(.$manufacurer))
```

I often create plots like in the example above to plot only subsets and would love to label automatically for the subset. At the moment, the `.` will not be recognised within the `ggtitle` but within `geom_text` it is working.

**EDIT:**
 Since I got a very nice comment and mark as duplicate from @Brian, is there maybe a solution to use this `{}` trick within the `dplyr::group_by` function? This is somehow not working. I would love to create individual plots for each group, but somehow only the complete data frame goes into the `ggplot` call.

```
mpg %>%
  group_by(manufacturer) %>% {
    ggplot(., aes(cyl, displ, color=manufacturer)) +
      geom_point() + 
      ggtitle(unique(.$manufacturer))
  }
```

It says Audi but prints all manufacturers in the single plot.

Comment: May be you can assign it to an object i.e. `p <- ggplot(...) + geom_text(...)`; Then extract the data i.e. `p + ggtitle(unique(p$data$manufacturer))`

Comment: Sounds like a good workaround. Is there any logical reason, why I can't access the data with `.`?

Comment: asked a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44025379/dplyr-and-ggplot-piping-is-not-working-as-expected) recently. But no solution yet.

Comment: I think the class is different i.e. Layer, LayerInstance, ggproto to extract the data

Comment: @akrun seems so `ggplot(mpg %>% filter(manufacturer == 'audi'), 
       aes(x = hwy, y = displ, label = model, title=quo_name(unique(manufacturer)))) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_text(data = . %>% filter(hwy > 28)) `

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I access the data frame that has been passed to ggplot()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45088454/how-do-i-access-the-data-frame-that-has-been-passed-to-ggplot)

Comment: You wrap the call to `ggplot` and its `+`-children with `{}`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45088522/3330437

Comment: @Brian this kind of solves my problem, but maybe an additional question, why is this not working with `group_by`? I added an example to my question but could also open a new question. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apply a ggplot-function per group with dplyr and set title per group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29034863/apply-a-ggplot-function-per-group-with-dplyr-and-set-title-per-group)

Comment: The `$` operator overrides/ignores grouping. I'm wondering if the dplyr `distinct` and `pull` verbs would help.

Answer (score 4):

I would try the following as it is not possible to pipe outside `aes()`.

```
ggplot(mpg %>% filter(manufacturer == 'audi'), 
       aes(x = hwy, y = displ, label = model)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_text(data = . %>% filter(hwy > 28)) +
  facet_wrap(~manufacturer)+
  theme(strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.text = element_text(hjust = 0, size = 14))
```

[image]

The idea is to use a facet with empty strip background. If there are more names or variables one has to create an extra faceting variable using e.g. `mutate(gr = "title")`

```
mpg %>% 
  mutate(title="This is my plot") %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = hwy, y = displ, col=manufacturer)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(~title)+
  theme(strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.text = element_text(hjust = 0, size = 14))
```

#### Edit

As you asked a second question here are two solutions for creating individual plots for each group

```
# first solution
p <- mpg %>%
  group_by(manufacturer) %>% 
     do(plots= ggplot(., aes(cyl, displ)) +
      geom_point() + 
      ggtitle(unique(.$manufacturer))
   )
p %>% slice(1) %>% .$plots


# second solution
mpg %>%
  nest(-manufacturer) %>%
  mutate(plot = map2(data, manufacturer, ~ggplot(data=.x,aes(cyl, displ))+
           geom_point() +
           ggtitle(.y))) %>% 
  slice(1) %>% .$plot
```

Or save the data using

```
map2(paste0(p$manufacturer, ".pdf"), p$plots, ggsave)
```

Comment: I used this already as a workaround but never thought of removing the background color. Good idea, actually this would be sufficient, since those graphs are often not for productive reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Here's two ways I've done this using `split`. You can use `split` to split your dataframe into a named list of dataframes, based on a variable. So calling `split(mpg, .$manufacturer)` gives you a list of dataframes, where each dataframe is associated with a manufacturer, e.g. `split_df$audi` is the dataframe of all observations made by Audi.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(ggplot2)

split_df <- split(mpg, .$manufacturer)
```

First way you could do this is to just call `ggplot` on a single item in the list. Since the list is named, `names(split_df)[1]` will give you the name, "audi".

```
ggplot(split_df[[1]], aes(x = hwy, y = displ, label = model)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    geom_text(data = . %>% filter(hwy > 28)) +
    ggtitle(names(split_df)[1])
```

[image]

That's kinda cumbersome, especially if you want plots for multiple manufacturers. When I've done this, I've used the map functions from `purrr`. What's really cool is `imap`, which maps over both the list and its names. Here I'm making a list of plots by mapping over the list of dataframes; each plot gets a title from the name of that list item.

```
plots <- imap(split_df, function(df, manufacturer) {
    ggplot(df, aes(x = hwy, y = displ, label = model)) +
        geom_point() +
        geom_text(data = . %>% filter(hwy > 28)) +
        ggtitle(manufacturer)
})

plots$audi
```

[image]

Then I can pull up a specific item from that list of plots. This is also handy for if you need to use `walk` to map over them and save every plot or a subset of plots, or if you need to use a `grid` function to arrange them into output, or really anything else cool that `purrr` is great for.

Answer (score 1):

Answering the follow-up about grouping by a variable to generate plots. I'm not sure how one would do this, nor what the output of a `group_by(foo) %>% ggplot()` call would be (generate the plots one by one? store them? make a big plot of all of them stacked?).

One way you might try this is via `lapply()`. Building on the solution you found to access the data from within the call:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

mfgs <- mpg %>% pull(manufacturer) %>% unique()
plot_list <- lapply(mfgs, function(mfg) {
  mpg %>%
  filter(manufacturer == mfg) %>% {
    ggplot(., aes(cyl, displ, color=manufacturer)) +
      geom_point() + 
      ggtitle(unique(.$manufacturer))
    }
})
```

From there, you can access a given plot with `plot_list[[i]]`, or (a) pass a named vector instead of `mfgs` as defined, or just set the names of the list to the supplied vector of manufacturers, which lets you call plots by name:

```
names(plot_list) <- mfgs
plot_list[["nissan"]]
```

Hope that helps.